# How to pick a smaller array from a larger array in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to pick 32 distinctive objects from an NSMutableArray of 75 objects. it can be 1 to 32, 2 to 33 or 10 to 42. What functions should i use to get the new array? Sorry for being noob.

Comment: So to be clear: must it be 32 consecutive objects, or 32 random unique objects?

Comment: nope, it doesn't, just need to get 32 objects. but consecutive is fine too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want N consecutive objects from a random index, try the following:

```
NSArray *arrayWithNConsecutiveObjects(NSArray *arr, int n)
{
    int subIdx = arc4random_uniform((unsigned) (arr.count - n));

    return [arr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(subIdx, n)];
}
```

If you need 32 random objects, you can extend this method to randomly sort the array:

```
NSArray *arrayWithNObjects(NSArray *arr, int n)
{
    arr = [arr sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        // random sort
        return arc4random_uniform(3) - 1; // one of -1, 0, and 1
    }];

    int subIdx = arc4random_uniform((unsigned) (arr.count - n));

    return [arr subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(subIdx, n)];
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Was one of the requirement was "distinctive objects"?

Comment: @user523234 yes, it was implied.

Comment: Since array can contains duplicated objects, perhaps my interpretation of the "distinctive objects" was not the same as the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the appropriate method inherited from `NSArray` to retrieve a slice of 32 consecutive elements:

```
int offset = 4;
NSArray *slice = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(offset, offset+32)];
```

Comment: Am I missing something here?  Was one of the requirement was "distinctive objects"?

Comment: There is a difference between distinct objects and not consecutive objects. My solutions has 32 distinct objects which are consecutive (as in his example 1 to 32, etc)

Comment: Since array can contains duplicated objects, perhaps my interpretation of the "distinctive objects" was not the same as the OP.